# export/import javascript class like module node into electron with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

In context of basic electon-vue app, I want to create my own javascript class and use it into main process or renderer or into vue component.

I created JS Class but I never find a good way for exporting my class.

All possibility of writing import/export module find in the web finished by same error : Undefined exports

```
"use strict"

import fs from 'fs'
import typeorm from 'typeorm'
import Public from './../entity/Public'

class ConnectionManager
{
    constructor(){}

    getConnection(type, name, options) {

    }
}

module.exports = ConnectionManager
```

But it seeams that others js file work perfectly like the vue-router js for routing into vue.js app :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: require('@/components/Home').default
    }
]
})
```

I package my code with Webpack and libraryTarget Output is : commonjs2

I seems that use babel-loader with webpack

node version : 10.13.0

electron : 3.0.10

Babel : 6

**EDIT :**

I try this syntax class js file :

```
"use strict"

import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'
import {Public} from './../entity/Public'

export default class ConnectionManager
{
    constructor(){}

    getConnection(type, name, options) {

    }
}
```

with this import syntax :

```
import ConnectionManager from './../service/connectionManager'
```

But I have this error when I execute code into electron :

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   _service_connectionManager__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.default.getConnection
>   is not a function

I console logged this service class "ConnectionManager" and I have this result (so it really exist) :

```
ƒ ConnectionManager() {
    babel_runtime_helpers_classCallCheck__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default()(this, ConnectionManager);
}
```

It seems that the final js module webpack contain the ConnectionManager class

Comment: How do you *use* the class? It looks like you're not creating an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you mix commonjs modules with ES modules by the wrong way.

There are a lot of modules (include node built-in) which have no [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export). To [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_an_entire_module's_contents) such a module you need to use `* as moduleAlias` or `{ exportedField }` in your import statement. Try to rewrite your code by this way:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'
import { Public } from '../entity/Public'

export default class ConnectionManager
{
    constructor(){}

    getConnection(type, name, options) {

    }
}
```

Because this class is [exported](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export) as a default value, you can use the following construction to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults) it as a default field, where ConnectionManager is an alias for the current scope:

```
import ConnectionManager from '../service/connectionManager'
```

Comment: It seems that good writing for this file but impossible to import this in others file. Webpack error which can't find function. But console.log this class seems to be good.

Comment: How do you import this class?

Comment: import * as ConnectionManager from './../service/connectionManager' or import ConnectionManager from './../service/connectionManager' or import {ConnectionManager} from './../service/connectionManager'

Comment: The second option is correct. Please provide more information if you still have an error.

Comment: You have an error in code which uses ConnectionManager. You use ConnectionManager as a function, but it's a class.

Comment: I have try lot of things and I have lot of code into comments. Before the new operator don't run but now it seems to be run perfeclty. I don't understand all the concept of import export ES6 webpack etc... but I have a solid base for working. Can you edit your response for complete export class example with import and after I valid your response ? Very thanks for your time and your help

Comment: Done. I've added a few links to MDN documentation, so I recommend you to read it attentively for better understanding of the subject. Good luck.